# Daily crontab with hg, git and svn

Tags: linux, bash, git, svn, cron

Hello I have made a script that updates some repos from git merc and svn, then updates a git repo. The script works manually but doesn't work in crontab, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/addonskins && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/aurora && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/bartender && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/dbm && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/elvui && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/elvui_enhanced && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/icehud && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/kuinameplates && /usr//bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/xct+ && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/kuinameplates && /usr/bin/git pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/postal && /usr/bin/svn update
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/recount && /usr/bin/svn update
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/rsa && /usr/bin/svn update
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/skada && /usr/bin/svn update
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/prat && /usr/bin/hg pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/askmrrobot && /usr/bin/hg pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons/prat && /usr/bin/hg pull
cd /var/gitrepo/addons && /usr/bin/git add .
cd /var/gitrepo/addons && /usr/bin/git commit -m 'Automatic update'
cd /var/gitrepo/addons && /usr/bin/git push
cd /var/gitrepo/addons && touch done.txt
```

It creates the done.txt file, but doesn't seem to run any of the svn updates at least

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you showed us your crontab command.

A few pointers first.

Use full paths when writing cron jobs:
eg.

```
03 05 * * * /bin/bash /home/user/myScript.sh
```

Also pipe the output to a log file for you viewing pleasure. Both stdout and stderr.
eg.

```
03 05 * * * /bin/bash /home/user/myScript.sh > ~/log/myScript.log 2>&1
```

See if the Cron job ran at all in the system log

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

These will be helpful when debugging. Now onto you question regarding git and svn

To get SVN working I used [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/10/08/some-notes-on-logging-and-ssh-access-from-cron-jobs) helpful guide(Capture here for reference):

```
First, install the keychain program. Second, add this to your ~/.bash_profile (we don't need this to run for every terminal, just on login):

# Use keychain to keep ssh-agent information available in a file
/usr/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
source $HOME/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh
Tweak as needed for the location of your private SSH keys. Also, make sure your .bash_profile is actually invoked at start-up. When logging into Ubuntu graphically, this may not be the case unless it's sourced in .profile.

Third, add this to the cron job script (if your cron job is a Python program, just wrap it in a shell script):

source $HOME/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh
```

As for SVN I haven't been able to get it working myself. Stumbled across your post when I was searching the same thing. Will update my answer if I find anything.
Update: You can use the config files in ~/.subversion to store your svn password